# I'm doing audio denoising and speech enhancement using machine learning and deep learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio, deep-learning, librosa

I have dataset which have clean and noisy audio files arounf 11500+. So, firstly i extract audio feature using librosa lib and then train the model.

But i am getting error during running fitting the model.

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import librosa
from tqdm import tqdm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout

# Define function to extract mel spectrogram features from an audio file
def extract_features(file_path):
    signal, sr = librosa.load(file_path, sr=16000)  # Load audio file
    signal = librosa.util.fix_length(signal, size = 16000*4) # pad or truncate signal to length of 4 sec 
    melspec = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=signal, sr=sr, n_fft=1024, hop_length=256) # Extract mel spectrogram
    melspec = librosa.power_to_db(melspec, ref=np.max) # Convert to log-magnitude (decibels)
    melspec = melspec / -80.0 # Normalize to range [0, 1]
    # Reshape to match the expected input shape of the model
    melspec = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(melspec, axis=-1), axis=0)
    return melspec

# Define the paths to the directories containing the clean and noisy audio files
clean_dir = './Clear Dataset'
noisy_dir = './Noise Dataset'

# Load the clean and noisy audio files and extract their features
clean_files = os.listdir(clean_dir)
noisy_files = os.listdir(noisy_dir)

clean_features = []
noisy_features = []
for clean_file, noisy_file in tqdm(zip(clean_files, noisy_files)):
    clean_path = os.path.join(clean_dir, clean_file)
    noisy_path = os.path.join(noisy_dir, noisy_file)
    clean_melspec = extract_features(clean_path)
    noisy_melspec = extract_features(noisy_path)
    clean_features.append(clean_melspec)
    noisy_features.append(noisy_melspec)

# Convert the feature lists to NumPy arrays
clean_features = np.array(clean_features)
noisy_features = np.array(noisy_features)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(noisy_features, clean_features, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(128, 251, 1)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 128, 251, 1)
X_test = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 128, 251, 1)
# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

In error, it is showing that *logits* and *labels* must have the same shape, received ((None, 128, 224, 1) vs (None, 1, 128, 251)).

Error look likes that:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\vv172\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\vv172\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\vv172\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\vv172\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1024, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\vv172\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1082, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\vv172\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\vv172\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 152, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\vv172\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 284, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\vv172\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 2176, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "C:\Users\vv172\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5680, in binary_crossentropy
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 128, 224, 1) vs (None, 1, 128, 251)).
```

Guide me how to solve this error.

Comment: Why do not add the Python tag instead of speech?

Comment: Sorry for that, do you have any idea for the solution?